# Prefetch and build cells for entire collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, collectionview

I have an array of tags. My `collectionView` shows a tag token for each tag. I allow users to search for the title of each tag and if there is a match in the array, the token is selected and moved to the 0 index of the array (and indexPath). This all works fine but I run into a crash when the user finds a match for a token that isn't displayed in the collectionView yet (in the case of long arrays of tags).

I've found examples to prefetch data (such as images) for collectionViews, but nothing that allows me to build the cells in advance.

This is my method that looks for matches in the array based on the user's input. I get the crash at the row where I construct the cell

```
let cell = ....
```

The crash is:

> "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value",

meaning the cell simply doesn't exist yet.

```
func insertNewTag() {
    guard let tagInput = tagTextField.text else { return }

    if let match = myTags.first(where: { $0.value == tagInput.lowercased() }) {
        print("Found a match")
        guard let indexOfMatch = myTags.index(where: {$0.value == match.value}) else { return }
        let indexPathOfMatch = IndexPath(item: indexOfMatch, section: 0)
        let cell = tagsCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPathOfMatch) as! AddTagCell
        if cell.cellIsSelected == true {
            print("Already selected, don't append")
        } else {
            cell.cellIsSelected = true
            selectedTags.append(match)
        }
        myTags.remove(at: indexOfMatch)
        myTags.insert(match, at: 0)
        let newIndexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
        tagsCollectionView.moveItem(at: indexPathOfMatch, to: newIndexPath)
    } else {
        print("No match, creating new tag")
        let dictionary = ["label": tagInput, "value": tagInput.lowercased()]
        let newTag = MyTag(uid: nil, dictionary: dictionary)
        myTags.insert(newTag, at: 0)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
        tagsCollectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
        let cell = tagsCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! AddTagCell
        cell.cellIsSelected = true
        selectedTags.append(newTag)
    }

    tagTextField.text = nil
}
```

I have tried to construct cells in the collectionView's prefetch method but led to nowhere.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, prefetchItemsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
    print("Prefetch: \(indexPaths)")
    for indexPath in indexPaths {
        let cell = tagsCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AddTagCell", for: indexPath) as! AddTagCell
        let tag = myTags[indexPath.row]
        cell.myTag = tag
        if let indices = selectedTagIndices {
            if indices.first(where: { $0 == indexPath.row }) != nil {
                cell.cellIsSelected = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am very thankful for any hints as to best solve this problem!!

Answer (score 0):

Cells are dequeued , you should have your model up to date with all the changes and reflect to the cells if exists , as a cell that is not visible is nil , you need

```
if let cell = tagsCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPathOfMatch) as? AddTagCell {
 ////
}
```

OR `guard` to write the code without inserting the below code in `{ }`

```
guard let cell = tagsCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPathOfMatch) as? AddTagCell else { return }
```

If the cell exists it'll be updated if not it will get latest changes from the model when it re-Appear again

Comment: Hm, so doing this will unfortunately ignore my code to select the cell and move it to the front as the cell doesn't exist yet. I was hoping to be able to select the cells that aren't visible.

Comment: move the code that updates the model up and   leave the if let or guard at most bottom to optionally update the cell if exists